# Does Redis automatically "memoize" or "recognize duplicates"?

Tags: redis

If you push two k,v pairs into Redis with the same value, that is

```
set(k1, v)
set(k2, v)
```

does Redis smarlty store v once behind the scenes and do something like:

```
set(somereference, v)
set(k1, #somereference)
set(k2, #somereference)
```

But still return the perception of `(k1, v), (k2, v)`?

I ask because Right now, from Python, I am pushing values into redis of the form:

```
pickle({"some sequence number" : xxx, "image-bytes" : some long bytestring})
```

And am wondering if it's worth restructuring how I'm doing this if two of these dicts actually contain the same image bytestring and redis would be able to only store the underlying value once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, redis doesn't deduplicate on its own:

```
redis$ du -h dump.rdb
4.0K    dump.rdb
redis$ ipython3

In [1]: %paste
import os
from redis import StrictRedis

data = os.urandom(1024)
redis = StrictRedis()

for i in range(1000000):
    redis.set(f'key{i}', data)
## -- End pasted text --

In [2]:
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)?
redis$ du -h dump.rdb
633M    dump.rdb
```

The database dump is compressed with LZW so it's a little smaller than the expected size.

As an aside, I've found [msgpack](https://msgpack.org/) to be much faster than pickle and pretty much everything else for packing and unpacking literals.

Comment: does msgpack support bytes? That was my main problem with JSON.

Comment: @Tommy: You have to enable some options but yes: `msgpack.unpackb(msgpack.packb(['a', b'a'], use_bin_type=True), raw=False) == ['a', b'a']`